# How to set up configurale, writable and enumberable properties in JavaScript Object constructor

Tags: javascript, properties

I am creating this Object constructor:

```
function Person(name, surname, yearOfBirth) {
this.name = name;
this.surname = surname;
this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth; };
```

But I want to modify configurable, enumerable and writable property?

I can do it on object literal like this:

```
var test = Object.create(Object.prototype, { name: {
value: 'Test',
enumerable:true,
writable:true,
configurable:true }});
```

Can I somehow do it in object constructor because I know I can do it like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(test, 'name', {configurable: false});
```

Can I somehow use same syntax as with object literal?

Because If it look's better than this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'name', {configurable: false});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), which does just the same but for all properties of an object instead of a particular name:

```
Object.defineProperty(test, 'name', {configurable: false});
Object.definePropertis(test, {
    name: {configurable: false}
});
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I didn't know about Object.defineProperties() method but now it seems logical... :)